# Perl name conflict with CPAN

Tags: database, perl, module, export

I also ways get the dbConnect not defined error. I can't seem to find the problem.
The dbConnect is hard code with password.

```
#! perl


use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;


use DBR qw(dbConnect query);

my $dbhead = dbConnect();
my $sql = "select * from mailing";
my @returned = query($dbhead,$sql);
```

The module which is saved in the save directory
named DB.pm. Which I cannot change name or content.

```
package GUI::DB;

use strict;
use DBI;
use warnings;


use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT);
use Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(dbConnect query);

#
# dbConnect - connect to the database, get the database handle
#
sub dbConnect {

    # Read database settings from config file:
    my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=test";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn,
            'abc',
            'password',
                            { RaiseError => 1 } 
);

    return $dbh;

}

#
# query - execute a query with parameters
#       query($dbh, $sql, @bindValues)
#
sub query {
    my $dbh = shift;
    my $sql = shift;
    my @bindValues = @_;            # 0 or several parameters

    my @returnData = ();

    # issue query
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    if ( @bindValues ) {
            $sth->execute(@bindValues);
    } else {
            $sth->execute();
    }

    if ( $sql =~ m/^select/i ) {
            while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
                    push @returnData, $row;
            }
    }

    # finish the sql statement
    $sth->finish();

    return @returnData;
}


__END__
```

I am hoping someone can see where I am doing wrong. I know the subroutine in the module works correctly since if I just write the code on the bottom of the module and run it it works.

Comment: DB is an *incredibly* bad name for a module. DB isn't just some random thing off of CPAN; it's the namespace reserved for the perl debugger.

Comment: I think there are even a few things that work differently in perl in a package DB...

Comment: can you show the first dozen or so lines of your DB.pm?

Comment: Aha! You have a package named "GUI::DB". You need to put it in a directory called `GUI` so that it can be loaded by `use GUI::DB`.

Comment: can i create a GUI directory in the current folder? I don't think I can add it to lib it will have premission problem.

Comment: I see a mismatch here: in the `use` statement you're using `DBR`, but the module's package is `GUI::DB`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
export PERL5LIB=.
```

before running your script

Alternatively, rename your module to something unique

Comment: I can't rename or change the content of DB.pm is there away to work around it. Where should I add export PERL5LIB

Comment: how about copying/symlinking DB.pm under an other name?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a bit messy...  The least-confusing way to get this working would be to find DBR.pm, create a GUI subdirectory (if one doesn't exist already), and move DBR.pm to GUI/DB.pm.  Then change `use DBR` to `use GUI::DB` and you should be set.

The easiest way to fix it would be to replace your `use DBR` line with:

```
use DBR;
GUI::DB->import(qw(dbConnect query));
```

...but that will continue to leave future maintainers confused by the `DBR`/`GUI::DB` mismatch.

The issue here is that `use DBR` is equivalent to `BEGIN { require DBR; DBR->import; }`, but the `package` in your `DBR.pm` file is named `GUI::DB`, so `DBR->import` does nothing - it's attempting to import symbols from the wrong package.  Manually calling `import` from the correct package (with `GUI::DB->import`) will fix this, *but* it's better to rename the module file (or alter the `package` name in that file) so that it will follow the standard convention of having the same name for both the file and the package it contains.